# Python TypeError while trying to work with Arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to fetch data from an uno over serial link (com3)and create substrings from iti am running anaconda, spyder(3.3.3) and pyserial 3.7

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM3",9600)
i = 1
while i < 6:
  line=ser.readline()

  print (line)
  x=x+1
  print(i)
  index1=line.index(",")
  index2=line.index(".")
  print(line[0:index1])
  print(line[index1+1,index2])

 ser.close()
```

ERROR:

> line 21, in 
>   index1=line.index(",")
>
> TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Comment: Are you sure that `line` is a string?? Try `index1=str(line).index(",")`

Answer (score 0):

You have an exception because you try to find index of unicode character "." in bytes.

`bytes` are ... just bytes (00-ff range). Ex. b"abc" in Python3.

`str` is string of unicode characters (a..z, ż, α etc.). Ex. "abc" in Python3.

You can use (if you expect text):

```py
line=ser.readline().decode()  # bytes -> unicode str
index2=line.index(".")
```

Or you can work on bytes (look at **b** before "."):

```py
line=ser.readline()
index2=line.index(b".")
```

P.S. You can see what you get typing: `print(repr(line))`.